# Livecode URL keyword

Tags: livecode

I have this code to access the URL content using `URL` keyword but I always got an error : `An error occured: error`. What have I missed?

```
on _common_parse_json pUrl

   put "http://www.google.com" into pUrl
   put URL pUrl into tResult   
   put the result into tError

   if tError is empty then      
      set the text of field "result" to tResult      
   else      
      set the text of field "result" to "An error occurred:" && tError & ", parsing URL:"&&pUrl      
   end if

end _common_parse_json
```

P.S I'm using Livecode 7.1.4 community edition in Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Duh! that problem happens because the `HTTP proxy` is not empty. Clearing that out makes everything working.

I don't know why it was not empty, this is a fresh install.

I bumped into someone else thread and I forgot the link related to this concern.

Hope this helps somebody else.

[image]